# Output username from user_id field on separate model in Django Template

Tags: python, django, authentication, templating

When a post is created, the user's User ID is saved to the post table under the user_id field. On the home page (for right now) I'm outputting all the posts in the post table. I want to get the username into the template based off of the user ID on the Post object.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_date DESC')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

home.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <a href="posts/{{post.id}}">{{ post.post_name }}</a>
        <p>{{ post.created_date }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.total_votes }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.user_id }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Ended up changing query to:

`SELECT 
    *, u.username 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN auth_user u ON (p.user_id = u.id)`

I didn't think you could add to the Post object and even call it as `post.username`. Regardless, if there's a better way to do it, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole logic is wrong :(

1. The user should be stored as a `ForeignKey` into the `Post` model. That is, a user may have multiple `Post`s but one `Post` may belong to one user. Something like that:

   ```
   class Post(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
       post_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
       total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       created_date = models.DateTimeField()
   ```

   Note that the `User` model may be the built-in Django `User` model (`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`) or you own if you have [customized it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/).
2. Database queries in Django, are **not** made with raw SQL. That's why the [ORM exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/). So, the view could be changed to:

   ```
   @login_required
   def home(request):
       posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')
       return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
   ```
3. Now you have a very verbose and pythonic access to the `User` model instance (and to the `Post` one) from your template.

   ```
   {% for post in posts %}
       <div>
           <a href="posts/{{post.id}}">{{ post.post_name }}</a>
           <p>{{ post.created_date }}</p>
           <p>{{ post.total_votes }}</p>
           <p>{{ post.user.username }}</p>
       </div>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

EXTRA TIP: Instead of `href="posts/{{post.id}}"`, try to use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag in order **not** to hardcode url paths like that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely aware that you shouldn't use raw sql in Django. I've just been having a hard time with finding what I need specifically in the documentation, and I'm still learning to use Django, so just used what I know to make it work at the moment. I did make the changes though, and it feels a lot better to be doing what I should be! Thanks! Also thanks for the `{% url %}` , will definitely use that as well

Comment: Also, could you explain the whole `related_name` property in the ForeignKey?

Comment: With the `related_name`, after you get an instance of `User` (say `user = User.objects.get(username='a_user_name')`), you can do this: `user.posts.all()` instead of `user.post_set.all()` (the `_set` is appended by Django, by default, if `related_name` is not set). It's more elegant and verbose. This, will get you all the posts created by the user with username `a_user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `ForeignKey` for such purpose. For example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Make sure to import `User` in `models.py`.

Create a `Form` for creating `Post`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_name',)
```

Now, in views:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return # Write return here
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'template_name', context)
```

Create a `template` for this and use it to create posts.

In your `view` home:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

In your `template`:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div>
    <a href="posts/{{post.id}}">{{ post.post_name }}</a>
    <p>{{ post.created_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.total_votes }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.user.username }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It will work.